# return value from SP and get it on Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a method

```
public void DeleteItem(int ImgId, int ImgNos, int ListId)
        {
            object[] objParams = {0,ImgId};
            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Conn, "DeleteItem",objParams);
            if (ItemNos == 2)
            {
                ChangeItem(ListId);
            }
        }
```

in deleteitem sp i am return the value as 0 or 1 now i want to get the return value on my btn click and want to check if return value is 0 then do some task and if return value is 1 then do some other task how to do that?

```
objGetBase.DeleteItem(ItemId, ItemNos, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ListId"]));
       // here i want to check the return value if return = 0 then go to next step else not            
string path1 = Path.Combine(GetDirectory(ItemName), ItemName);
File.Delete(path1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Microsoft library with SqlHelper?

If you are things are quite simple, if you use `ExecuteScalar`, instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` you will get returned an object.

here is a link to some examples using that Libraray:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647281.aspx

From this it should be quite straightforward:

`int returnValue = (int)SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(Conn, "DeleteItem",objParams);`

Comment: I am getting object reference null exc

Comment: does it work if you dont try and type it to int and just output it to var?